# What new packages should I download using SDK Manager

Tags: android, qt, sdk, package

The new version of *SDK* for *Qt 5.12* doesn't include *SDK Manager* in the *Tool* folder, hence I needed *Android Studio* to Add/Remove the packages.

I know that APIs must be chosen based on the target and purposes. But since the APIs are new (28) and there are different options to download, it's rather puzzling what to download.

I don't have a real Android device nor want I use the *Emulator*. I merely wish to **Build** the program using Android kits and create *APK* files from them. Afterwards I will test those APK files on real Android devices which include new or middle aged smartphones and tablets.

For these purposes what packages should I install, for instance, what check boxes are needed to be checked here in the screenshot below. I will repeat the pattern for a number of lower APIs then.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an emulator, then you don't want the "system images".

As for the API level, it really depends on what is the minimum API you want to target. If you download only the latest API, you significantly limit your targets, as the app will only run on the latest and greatest version of Android.

The safe lower limit seems to be API level 19, which is android 4.4. So you can use that to build your apps, and they will run on any version onward.

Additionally, if you want to publish to the market, you will have to set your target API to some of the latest versions, because google won't accept any older. Note that the "target SDK" is different from the "minimum required SDK", which you can still have at version 19.

There isn't much point in installing the latest SDK versions, as Qt isn't really using their features, I mean unless you are doing some Java native android app development.

The documentation for Qt 5.12 says "API 21", but 19 seems to work just fine, and it allows to target older devices that are stuck without OS updates - currently around 7-8% of active devices. Still, if you don't care about that, you should go with the recommended API version 21.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. Two more questions, please: **1-** For every Android, for example, **9**, **8.1**, **8** shown above in the screenshot, I only tick the first two options, because the rest are all *System Images* and I don't need them, then repeat this for other APIs downwards until API 19. Do you agree with this? And **2-** Has it any difference whether I use *Android Studio SDK Manager* for this task or the *Built-in SDK Manager* in the *Tools* folder? (I installed an old version of *Android SDK Tools* and it gave me that *sdk Manager*.)

Comment: No, you only need one -  API 19 (or 21) and only the "SDK Platform" and the sources, the images are for the emulator. You will also needs the "tools" - namely the "Android SDK Tools" the "Build-Tools" and the "Platform-Tools". It doesn't matter which manager you use as long as it works.

Comment: Will it be a problem if I install both API 19 and 21, please? (And why not the middle, 20!)

Comment: No problem whatsoever. They do not depend on each other.

Comment: Thanks for your help. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/0e0bOtv) is a screenshot of the final status of packages I installed. Please have a look to know whether or not some item is needed to be added/removed.

Comment: You went a bit overboard, but it should be OK.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. :)